# Установка вычислительных узлов кластера

Tags: hpc, cluster, windows-server

Здравствуйте!

Возникла такая проблема. Имеется аудитория в которой 4 компа, соединенные в сеть. На один из них, на "главный", была установлена Win Server 2008 R2 HPC Edition, на остальных стоит Xp. На главный на главный также утановили HPC Pack R2. Произвели настройку согласно этому [ресурсу](http://vc.ulstu.ru/panel/doc/deployment-hpc.html). НООО!!! Теперь мы не можем установить вычислительные узлы для кластера, так как главный комп не видит остальные. Остальные компы находятся в одной рабочей группе, а у главного установлен domain. Мы пытались для остальных установит тоже такой но не вышло. Да и группу на главном теперь тоже изменить нельзя.

Что нужно сделать? Подскажите...

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> Что нужно сделать?

- Введите в домен все вычислительные узлы, для начала.
- После чего, убедитесь, что все эти узлы адекватно работают в доменной инфраструктуре: разрешаются по имени, видят контроллер домена, не имеют проблем в логах и т.п.
- Назовите вычислительные узлы как-нибудь так: node-01, node-02, node-03, ...
- Перенастройте HPC.
- Создайте шаблон.
- Выберите шаблоном узлы.
- Проведите диагностику (все тесты).

Comment: To @Leshij_2005. Забудьте о HPC в винде. Переходите на линукс.